# What is the probability a random function is order preserving?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two finite partial order sets. Consider the space of all functions from X to Y with uniform distribution. Let $\phi : X\to Y$ be a random element of this space. I was wondering if there is a general way to calculate the probability (or find a good bound) that $\phi$ be an order preserving map?

Or in specific:

Let $n$, $m$ and $t$ be natural numbers which $t\leq\frac{m}{2}$. Let 
$$X=\{(A,B) : A,B\neq\emptyset , A\cap B=\emptyset , A,B\subseteq\{1,2,\cdots , n\}\}$$
and 
$$Y=\{(A,B) : A\cap B=\emptyset , A,B\subseteq\{1,2,\cdots , m\}, |A|,|B|\geq t\}$$
be two partial order sets which $(A,B)\leq (C,D)$ if and only if $A\subseteq C$ and $B\subseteq D$. What is the probability that a random function from X to Y be an order preserving map?